# How to set returned samples frequency in Prometheus query?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm querying a metric's values over a period of time like `metric_name[1w]` which returns a metric value for *every* timestamp. And the timestamps' frequency is set by the `scrape_interval` parameter in Prometheus config as far as I understand.

I would like to alter that samples' frequency through the query, without changing the scrape interval. I want to get not every sample but, for example, a sample for every 10 seconds, or a sample for every 30 seconds, or a sample for every 5 minutes, etc. How do I do it with PromQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `metric_name[1w:10s]`, e.g. to put the desired step interval (10s in this case) after a colon in square brackets. This enables [subquery functionality](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) in PromQL.